# Tomcat Docker Container doesn't run on Windows

Tags: windows, docker-for-windows, tomcat8.5, docker

I was trying to run tomcat 8.5 docker container on my windows-10 machine using the following command:

```
docker container run -it -p 8080:8088 --rm tomcat:8.5
```

The container starts successfully, but I cannot really see the tomcat's welcome page. When I tried to use the following, none of them worked:

`localhost:8080`

`localhost:8088`

`fully-qualified-computer-name:8080`

`fully-qualified-computer-name:8088`

I am assuming that there is a setting that needs to be enabled/disabled from somewhere within windows. Has anyone done this on their windows machine?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay rookie mistake and just remembered "Windows Firewall from Control Panel". You need to set an outbound/inbound rule for TCP port. Ideally within private (and protected if you are sitting within a secure firewalled VPN). That solved the issue.